# How to get parameters from URL while in an EventSubscriber?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

`$id` is always null when it shouldn't be. I'm able to retrieve the $id value via my controller but not from my EventSubscriber.

How do I correctly retrieve parameters from the URL via my EventSubscriber with `FilterControllerEvent`?

```
class TestVerificationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $testService;
    public function __construct(TestService $testService)
    {
        $this->testService = $testService;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of event names this subscriber wants to listen to.
     *
     * The array keys are event names and the value can be:
     *
     *  * The method name to call (priority defaults to 0)
     *  * An array composed of the method name to call and the priority
     *  * An array of arrays composed of the method names to call and respective
     *    priorities, or 0 if unset
     *
     * For instance:
     *
     *  * array('eventName' => 'methodName')
     *  * array('eventName' => array('methodName', $priority))
     *  * array('eventName' => array(array('methodName1', $priority), array('methodName2')))
     *
     * @return array The event names to listen to
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
        );
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event){
        $controller = $event->getController();

        /*
         * $controller passed can be either a class or a Closure.
         * This is not usual in Symfony but it may happen.
         * If it is a class, it comes in array format
         */
        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($controller[0] instanceof TestVerificationController) {
            //this always returns null
            $id = $event->getRequest()->query->get('id');
            if(!$id){
                throw new CustomApiException(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "Could not verify that the test exists.");
            }
            $this->testService->checkAndUpdateWithId($id);
        }
    }

}
```

My only assumptions at this point is that maybe at this specific moment, symfony hasn't fully processed the request?

Comment: There is some info here: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/dpv0/getting-full-information-about-the-request-with-on-kernel-controller-event-listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would appear that the data was processed but just under this:

```
$id = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get("id");
```

Comment: If it's from the URL you could use `->query->get("id")` instead of `attributes` but yeah seems like you got it

Comment: @FlorentDestremau that is what I previously tried, however it always returned null

Comment: are you sure it is stored in the query parameters and not in a `post` body then ?

Comment: @FlorentDesrem yes, the id is in the URL and not from the body.